# Unable to start Spring Boot on Google App Engine Standard with MongoDB Atlas instance

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, google-app-engine, mongodb-atlas

I have got MongoDB Atlas instance up and running. It also be able to connect from Spring Boot app from my PC using GAE maven plugin => appengine:run. However when I deploy the app to GAE standard when the application, Spring Boot failed to start with below exception

ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validatingMongoEventListener' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.event.ValidatingMongoEventListener]: Factory method 'validatingMongoEventListener' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'validator' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000183: Unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'. Check that you have the EL dependencies on the classpath, or use ParameterMessageInterpolator instead

Does anyone have any idea?